# Match string with another string having dynamic string content

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to match a 1st string with a 2nd string. The second string will have dynamic content inside **{}**. It is also separated by **|** since I need to match the 1st string with 2nd string's multiple values and return boolean. Also, I need the dynamic variables from 1st string if the 1st string value matches with 2nd string's partial value. I have tried and searched a lot and came up to this

```
$message = "wala hi";
$pattern = "Mujhey|mujhe|mujh'y|mjy?|mujy|wala {dynamicontent}";
$pattern = str_replace('/', '\/', $pattern);
$text = '/^'.preg_replace('/\{((?:(?!\d+,?\d+?)\w)+?)\}/', '(?<$1>.*)', $pattern).' ?$/miu';
$regexMatched = (bool) preg_match($text, $message, $matches) || (bool) preg_match($text, '', $matches);
var_dump([$regexMatched, $matches]);
```

It's still not working properly.

following can be the inputs, pattern to match = and the desired outputs:

1. input: play demo-song, pattern: play {song}, output: returns true and demo-song
2. input: pley demo-song, pattern: play {song}, output: returns false and null
3. input: show hoizer profile, pattern: show {artist} profile, output: returns true and hoizer
4. input: show 2019 season of GOT, pattern: show {year} season of {series}, output: returns true and [0=>2019, 1=>GOT]

PS: The strings will contain emojis and **?,'** as well.

Comment: @Emma i have mentioned the outputs can you kindly check

Comment: actually what i am trying is to match an input string with a predefined string pattern. the input string will contain text emojis and other special characters for e.g(i am a student) or (I'm a student). this input needs to be matched with the multiple predefined pattern seperated with **|** for e.g(i am a {profession}|I'm a {profession}). in this case preg_match should return true and with the result i want to get the **student** word.

Comment: it would be easier if we preg_replace the pattern string surrounded by {} and ignore it in preg_match and if the rest of the input string matches with the pattern string we get the boolean result true with the input ignored string. for e.g word student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is the solution which fulfills my requirement. Thank you for your help @Emma.

```
function checkPattern($stringToTest, $pattern) {
    str_replace("\|", "|", preg_quote($pattern));
    $pattern = str_replace("|", "$|^", preg_replace('/' . preg_quote('{') . '.*?' .preg_quote('}') . '/', '(.*)', $pattern));
    $regexMatched = (bool) preg_match("/^".$pattern."$/mi", $stringToTest, $matches);
    var_dump([$regexMatched, end($matches)]);
}

//test 1 returns [true, hozier]
$stringToTest = "play songs by hozier";
$pattern = "play songs by {artist}|play {artist} songs|{artist} songs"; 
checkPattern($stringToTest, $pattern);

//test 2 returns [false, false]
$stringToTest = "show hozier";
$pattern = "show {artist} profile|view {artist} profile"; 
checkPattern($stringToTest, $pattern);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing that you have several sentences with various components, and you wish to extract or replace some desired part of those.

---

You'd likely want to possibly first categorize your inputs, then pass it through some functions to match or replace. This general expression might be OK to just take a look and see how you would like to design and write some expressions for your inputs:

```
play\s+([^,]+?)\s*,|show\s+(.*?)\s+profile|show\s+(\d{4})\s+season\s+of\s+([^,]+?)\s*,|i(?:'m)?\s+.*?(?:\ba\b|\ban\b)\s+(\S+)
```

If you may have faced some technical issues on some specific expressions, you can maybe post them one by one perhaps with some real inputs and desired outputs.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/n8lGJ5/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/n8lGJ5/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Test

```
$re = '/play\s+([^,]+?)\s*,|show\s+(.*?)\s+profile|show\s+(\d{4})\s+season\s+of\s+([^,]+?)\s*,|i(?:\'m)?\s+.*?(?:\ba\b|\ban\b)\s+(\S+)/mi';
$str = 'play demo-song, pattern: play {song},
show hoizer profile, pattern: show {artist} profile
show 2019 season of GOT, pattern: show {year} season of {series},

PLAY demo-song, pattern: PLay {song},
SHOW hoizer some other artists profile, pattern: show {artist} profile
show   2019 SEASON   OF  GOT  , pattern: show {year} season of {series},

i am a student I AM  A programmer i\'m a suergeon pattern: I\'m a {profession}, ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: i have came up to [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c13bdb20de9f866dfee267a4b2694e84307fad6) solution since your answer gave me little idea. Is this a right solution. works fine for me or can it be more optimized?